# Flutterflow: Disable swiping upwards and only on certain pages PageView

Tags: flutterflow

I am using this in my app: https://docs.flutterflow.io/widgets-and-components/widgets/layout-elements/pageview

I want to disable swiping up completely, only swiping down should work. And I want to disable swiping entirely on some pages (so that only buttons work). Is this possible?

Additionally: If this is not possible in the Flutterflow UI , can I write custom functions to achieve this?